Why does Postfix lookup the sender when resolving transport maps?
Email for our clients are hosted on a few different internal mail stores.
I'm using the tcp_table transport lookup protocol to assess which internal server the mail should go to, but noted that postfix is also looking up the domain in MAIL FROM, not only RCPT TO. Why does it need to do that?
It might not be the end of the world, but I see a potential to cut the number of transport queries in half.
I tried setting sender_dependent_relayhost_maps to static:DUNNO in an attempt to tell postfix that routing is not dependent on the sender.
I'd also like to have it skip the * queries, but it's less of a deal, since my TCP daemon is hard-coded to return a 500 Not found (funny that they chose 200 for OK, but 500 for Not found).
